# Haskell binding to variable Vs inline declaration

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I'm writing a compiler from JSON to some other format. I don't understand the difference between binding an expression to a variable versus passing it inline, here's two examples (inside a `do` block) which I expect to work the same, but instead the second one confuses the typechecker and fails:

Works as expected

```
modul <- parseModule <$> readFile "foo.json"
case (modul) of
        (Left s) -> error s
        (Right m) -> what (m :: Module) `shouldBe` "module"
```

Fails typechecking

```
case (parseModule <$> readFile "foo.json") of
        (Left s) -> error s
        (Right m) -> what (m :: Module) `shouldBe` "module"
```

Error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘Either a0’ with ‘IO’
  Expected type: IO (Either String Module)
    Actual type: Either a0 (Either String Module)
```

Comment: The error message is usually pretty explicit about the expected type and the actual type. The important detail is that the `<-` syntax in a `do` block is not assignment. The type of the expression that's bound does not match the type of the pattern bound to it. (If they were the same, it'd be redundant with `let` statements in a `do` block.)

Comment: can you try the following `case modul <- parseModule <$> readFile "foo.json" of ..` - I think that one should work, because here you still execute the (IO) action of interacting with the filesystem and read in the file wheras the latter only looks at the action to be done. Think of it like checking the results of a recipe, e.g. is the cake good (`Right`) or bad (`Left`), and checking the recipe itself - which doesn't make sense - the recipe is neither good nor bad - only its result.

Comment: Thanks, I added the error in the question. @epsilonhalbe looks like you're correct, the error has to do with weather `parseModule <$> readFile "foo.json"` is evaluated early or late. Can I use something like `seq` or is the binding to `modul` the only way to do it even inline?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe I have never seen `<-` used inside a `case of`. GHCi 8.0 rejects it. Is that valid syntax in newer GHCs?

Comment: I've seen this syntax in a codebase at work which was then using ghc 7.x so it must have been around for a while. I guess it not working is either because of ghci or the newer ghc. Maybe I should have added a disclaimer that i would NOT recommend using this syntax, though valid I think it is really confusing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parseModule <$> readFile "foo.json"` is not a value that you could pattern-match on. That value wouldn't be purely functional, because it depends on a real-world resource (the file).

Instead, it is an *IO action* which is able to obtain the value when executed (it then takes a “snapshot of the world state, frozen into a pure value”).

Really, there's only one way to execute IO actions: assign them to the name `main`, compile and run. That may sound crazy prohibitive – you can only have *one single action* in a program? – but actually it's not, because you can combine multiple actions (to be executed sequentially) into a single action and execute that. This *composing of actions* is accomplished through the concept of *monads*. In your case, you basically want to compose the action of type `IO (Either String Module)` with a function of type `Either String Module -> IO ()`. That's what the [`>>=` operator](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Instances.html#v:-62--62--61-) is for.

```
main :: IO ()
main = parseModule <$> readFile "foo.json" >>= f
 where f modul = case modul of ...
```

...or in lambda-style,

```
main = parseModule <$> readFile "foo.json"
      >>= \modul -> case modul of
            Left s  -> error s
            Right m -> what m `shouldBe` "module"
```

Because that kind of binding is needed so often, Haskell has the special `do` syntax for it, which you've already used in the first snippet. It is simply syntactic sugar for this `>>=` operator chain, but that monadic bind is essential.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! So I guess the `do` syntax:
`do { x <- expr(); f(x); }` is just syntactic sugar for something like this:
`expr >>= f` ? Also, in both cases the expr() is evaluated and becomes bound to a result, instead of passing the thunk around?

Comment: @rausted Precisely correct on the sugar point. The details of the sugar are given [in the Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14). As for the comment about "evaluated and becomes not a thunk": no, that comment is off-target. "Evaluated" (thunk-ness) and "executed" (the actual input/output has been done) are separate concepts; an action can be converted from a thunk to an evaluated thing without having been executed.

Comment: @DanielWagner I don't get it, how can a symbolic expression involving IO let's say, be evaluated without being executed? And does bind evaluate, execute or none of the above?

Comment: @rausted When something is _evaluated_, nothing really happens, except perhaps the processor getting warm from local constants being pre-calculated into normal form. Evaluation only ever happens once for any given Haskell value (when an already-evaluated value is used again it'll simply have everything in memory already). For IO actions, evaluation normally doesn't do anything at all – you basically just get the confirmation _yes, this is something that could be executed_. OTOH, execution is _specific_ to IO actions, and is always accomplished through a monadic bind to `main`.

Comment: ...The bind itself does neither evaluate nor execute an IO action, but it allows the runtime to execute it as soon as the control flow arrives there.

Comment: Alright I think I got it, thanks for the great answers!

Comment: @rausted I admit I don't know how to answer "How can an IO action be evaluated without being executed?". You just... do it. Imagine this: I write down `if isPrime (1e1000+1) then putStrLn "Hiya, rausted!" else launchMissiles`. Evaluation is the process of deciding whether to warmly greet you or blow up the world; execution is then acting on that decision. As for bind, it does none of the above, it just is another way to construct an IO action. Evaluation and execution don't happen from within the language.